# Appending user input row by row to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have spent the past two days on this and I've drawn blank, hopefully someone can help.

I have 3 values assigned to variables that are always going to be the same. I then have a fourth value assigned to a variable that is going to be different each time on user input. The intention is to take user input for all 4 values. On the fourth value I want the program to ask me for input repeatedly until I press "q" for example. Each time I enter a value it appends to a CSV file with the existing 3 values already entered. After q, continue with the script.

```
value1 = input("enter value1 ")
value2 = input("enter value2 ")
value3 = input("enter value3 ")
value4 = input("enter value4 ")
value4 = input("enter value4 ")
...
...
...
q
```

**CSV file** should be like this, ensuring that the first three values are constant but the fourth value is different per each entry.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
value1,value2,value3,something_new
value1,value2,value3,something_new2
value1,value2,value3,something_new3
value1,value2,value3,something_new4
value1,value2,value3,something_new5
value1,value2,value3,something_new6
...
...
...
```

I had the below code that takes the values and adds 1 row in a CSV file each time. I've tried using file mode 'a' but I can't seem to add a new row in the CSV for the next. And when I add a for loop to the code below I get the "TypeError: 'DictWriter' object is not iterable" error.

```
with open('file_append.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'column1': value1, 'column2': value2, 'column3': value3, 'column4': value4})
```

I'm getting lost on adding for/while loops, if statements, if anyone can't point me in the right direction or show me a working solution it would be much appreciated

I have looked at many stack overflows and blogs but nothing is helping me solve this.

[how to append to a new row when writing to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952254/how-to-append-to-a-new-row-when-writing-to-csv-file)

[How to append new data onto a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839803/how-to-append-new-data-onto-a-new-line)

[Appending data to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111416/appending-data-to-csv-file)

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a complete example where you are hitting this issue? Your code above (writing to `file_append.csv`) looks like it would run without any issues. I'm unsure how you're using writer to end up getting the `object is not iterable` error.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete - the input part is missing.
Id' rather go and collect the user's input in a loop and then write to the file. For that, you only have to loop the `writerow` part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import csv
value1 = input("enter value1 ")
value2 = input("enter value2 ")
value3 = input("enter value3 ")
value4 = '0'

data = []

while True:
    value4 = input("enter value4 ")
    if value4.upper() == "Q":
        break
    data.append([value1,value2,value3,value4])
    

with open('file_append.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    fieldnames = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)

import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file_append.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this. This snippet uses the so-called "walrus operator" (`:=`), which is only available in Python 3.8. It also uses f-strings, which are available since Python 3.6. Neither of these features are strictly required, and it's trivial to rewrite the code without these features if necessary. The `itertools` import is also not required, it's just a cute way of counting starting at 1, going upwards. Naturally, you can use a `DictWriter`, if you like.

```
def main():

    import csv
    import itertools

    fieldnames = ["fruit", "beverage", "desert", "name"]

    with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:

        constant_values = [input(f"What {fieldname} does the diet consist of?: ") for fieldname in fieldnames[:-1]]
        
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)
        
        count = itertools.count(1)
        while (name := input(f"What is the name of person# {next(count)}?: ")) != "q":
            writer.writerow(constant_values + [name])
        print("Done!")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
What fruit does the diet consist of?: Apple
What beverage does the diet consist of?: Coke
What desert does the diet consist of?: Ice Cream
What is the name of person# 1?: John
What is the name of person# 2?: Jerry
What is the name of person# 3?: George
What is the name of person# 4?: Harry
What is the name of person# 5?: Sam
What is the name of person# 6?: q
Done!
>>>
```

CSV file:

```
fruit,beverage,desert,name
Apple,Coke,Ice Cream,John
Apple,Coke,Ice Cream,Jerry
Apple,Coke,Ice Cream,George
Apple,Coke,Ice Cream,Harry
Apple,Coke,Ice Cream,Sam
```

Comment: Also worked well and nice to know some other features, thank you!